# How to return exceed 6M XML file content in Lambda function Python?

Tags: python, xml, aws-lambda, limit

I provided an API Gateway's URL to my client, and this API Gateway will trigger a Lambda function. The Lambda function program read the xml file content from AWS S3 first and then return this xml content to client.

The problem is: If the xml file size less then 6M, this Lambda function works well, it can return the xml file to client correctly.

If the xml file size more then 6M, the Lambda function will return an error:

```
2022-06-30T08:59:24.975-04:00 [ERROR] [1656593964975] LAMBDA_RUNTIME Failed to post handler success response. Http response code: 413.

2022-06-30T08:59:24.975-04:00 Traceback (most recent call last):

2022-06-30T08:59:24.975-04:00 File "/var/runtime/bootstrap.py", line 60, in

2022-06-30T08:59:24.975-04:00 main()

2022-06-30T08:59:24.975-04:00 File "/var/runtime/bootstrap.py", line 57, in main

2022-06-30T08:59:24.975-04:00 awslambdaricmain.main([os.environ["LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT"], os.environ["_HANDLER"]])

2022-06-30T08:59:24.975-04:00 File "/var/runtime/awslambdaric/main.py", line 21, in main

2022-06-30T08:59:24.976-04:00 bootstrap.run(app_root, handler, lambda_runtime_api_addr)

2022-06-30T08:59:24.976-04:00 File "/var/runtime/awslambdaric/bootstrap.py", line 405, in run

2022-06-30T08:59:24.976-04:00 handle_event_request(

2022-06-30T08:59:24.976-04:00 File "/var/runtime/awslambdaric/bootstrap.py", line 176, in handle_event_request

2022-06-30T08:59:24.976-04:00 lambda_runtime_client.post_invocation_result(

2022-06-30T08:59:24.976-04:00 File "/var/runtime/awslambdaric/lambda_runtime_client.py", line 83, in post_invocation_result

2022-06-30T08:59:24.976-04:00 runtime_client.post_invocation_result(

2022-06-30T08:59:24.976-04:00 RuntimeError: Failed to post invocation response

2022-06-30T08:59:25.599-04:00 END RequestId: 42359cf6-5313-444d-8253-b81c2a1eea29

2022-06-30T08:59:25.599-04:00 REPORT RequestId: 42359cf6-5313-444d-8253-b81c2a1eea29 Duration: 2143.11 ms Billed Duration: 2144 ms Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 108 MB Init Duration: 343.16 ms

2022-06-30T08:59:25.599-04:00 RequestId: 42359cf6-5313-444d-8253-b81c2a1eea29 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1 Runtime.ExitError
```

Anybody has the solutions for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've hit a hard limit for Lambda. The work around would be to send a download link to S3 so the client can download directly from there.

You can use pre signed URLs to make sure this is still secure.